# Read sqlite from request body in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I want to read the sqlite database from request body without saving it into temporary file.

The request has been sent by:

`curl -X POST --data-binary @mydb.sqlite3 -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" "http://localhost:8000/upload_sqlite"`

My view function like this:

```py
def upload_sqlite(request):
    print(request.body)

    conn = sqlite3.connect(request.body)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")

    # do something

    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

And the console output is here:

```py
b'SQLite format 3\x00\x04\x00\x01\x01\x00@  \x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x0...'

...ignored...

  File "/path/to/views.py", line 208, in upload_sqlite
    conn = sqlite3.connect(request.body)
ValueError: embedded null byte
```

---

2019.11.20 update:

Currently solution by `tempfile`:

```py
def upload_sqlite(request):
    fd, filename = tempfile.mkstemp()

    os.write(fd, request.body)
    conn = sqlite3.connect(filename)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")

    # do something

    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    os.close(fd)

    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Comment: There's a way to do it in C, but the Python bindings don't export the necessary API. (https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/deserialize.html)

Comment: Thanks @Shawn. It seems like the only way to do this is to create a temporary file until Python's sqlite supports serialize/deserialize functions...

Comment: It might be possible to write a wrapper around the C deserialize function with [Cython](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/clibraries.html)